# Redefine eqnarray environment to render its content in red

Tags: environments

For (copy) editing purposes I'd like to redefine the eqnarray envinronment to render its content in red (or any other colour). How can I do it?

**Edit.** I'll use this trick to better spot and (eventually) change the instances of eqnarray.

Comment: It would be better to explain *why* you want it. I remember about your job, other people might not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `etoolbox` can do the trick

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{eqnarray*}{\color{red}}
\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \dot x &=& v \\
  \dot v &=& F(x)
\end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, [one shouldn't use `eqnarray`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/2417). A similar approach to the suggestion by @Denys Potapov works with the `align` environment from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). Note that the equation numbers will be coloured with `align`, whereas I don't think they will with `eqnarray`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\let\oldalign\align
\def\align{%
\color{red}\oldalign}
\begin{document}
abc
\begin{align}
a &= b \\
  &= c
\end{align}
def
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess that the OP's aim is to visually find the instances of `eqnarray` so to be able to change them in the source.

Comment: @egreg --- I fully support any effort to find and remove instances of `eqnarray`.

Comment: The OP explained time ago that he's in charge of copy editing, so my guess.

Comment: @egreg Indeed i'll use this trick to better spot and (eventually) change the instances of `eqnarray` ;-)